# select statement and while loop for a variable pulled from a table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One with Cities and zips (table2), the other with general info and the zip(table1).

I am pulling info from table1 plus the zip. Everything works fine. Now I want to pull the city from table2 using zip pulled from table1.

I am not sure what to use to do so.

> table1: busName,street,zip
>
> table2: zip,city,county

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT busName, street, zip, status, phone, type, subType 
        FROM business
        WHERE busName
```

My select for the city request:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT city FROM cities WHERE zip=$zip");
```

Putting in a while loop and it will only do 1 round:

```
while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $busName=$r["busName"];
            $busStreet2=$r["street"];
            $zip=$r["zip"];

do this

}
```

I just need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You should probably be using a [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) statement in your query. `FROM business JOIN city ON business.zip = city.zip`

Comment: Yep, that was it. I knew I was being stupid just couldn't figure out how.